# how to sort a generic hash map with string and integer with value set in java

Tags: java

how to sort a generic hash map with string and integer with value set in java :

here is the answer for that but need to figureout a optimised way out of it .

```
    HashMap<String,Integer> hash = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    hash.put("king", 2);
    hash.put("Queen", 3);
    hash.put("Pawn", 1);
    hash.put("Minister", 7);
    hash.put("Horse", 6);

    List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> list =
            new LinkedList<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>( hash.entrySet());

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>() {
         public int compare( Map.Entry<String,Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String,Integer> o2 )
            {
                return (o1.getValue()).compareTo( o2.getValue() );
            }
    });

     Map<String,Integer> result = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();

     for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : list)
        {
            System.out.println( entry.getKey()+" === "+entry.getValue() );
        }
```

Comment: Optimized in what sense?

Comment: Is this a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: It would be helpful to know the purposes of this data structure and what use cases are in need of optimization. It may be that different data structure(s) would better suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, there is not much to optimize, except changing your collection for a ordered one and not a HashMap.

Your code is not really bad, the complexity is in order of *n log(n)* caused by `Collections.sort()`

otherwise you have a step you could avoid by not creating a new collection, and starting with an ordered collection. `List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> list = LinkedList<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>( hash.entrySet());`

Comment: If by "ordered collection" you mean SortedMap, that wouldn't work. He wants the entries to be sorted by value (not by key).